# How do I get the last value from a ReplaySubject?

Tags: rxjs

Below is a snippet that describes what I'm trying to do.  In my application I have a replaysubject that's used throughout.  At a certain point I want to get the last value emitted from the subject, but `last` doesn't seem to work on a ReplaySubject.

```
const subject = new Rx.ReplaySubject();

subject.next(1);
subject.next(2);
subject.next(3);
subject.next(4);

subject.subscribe(num => console.log(num));

var lastObserver = subject.last();
lastObserver.subscribe(num => console.log('last: ' + num));
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/b05r434a/5/)

The code above doesn't fire anything for the `lastObserver`, but subscribe works just fine.

Answer (score 16):

Maybe your confusion is about how the `.last()` operator is supposed to work?

`.last()` should wait for a stream to complete, then give you the last value emitted before the stream ended. So in order for it to work, the stream will need to end.

I believe your `lastObserver` will emit as soon as the subject completes.

```
const subject = new Rx.ReplaySubject();

subject.next(1);
subject.next(2);
subject.next(3);
subject.next(4);

subject.subscribe(num => console.log(num));
subject.complete(); // end your stream here
var lastObserver = subject.last();
lastObserver.subscribe(num => console.log('last: ' + num));
```

If you don't want your stream to end, but you do want subscribers to receive the last value emitted before subscription, consider reaching for `BehaviorSubject`, which was designed for this use case.

Comment: using BehaviorSubject was the key for my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I do like this:

`debounce` ignores all happened before and leaves the last one

```
const subject = new Rx.ReplaySubject();

subject.next(1);
subject.next(2);
subject.next(3);
subject.next(4);

subject
.pipe(debounceTime(0), take(1))
.subscribe(num => console.log('last: ' + num));
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Oh thank you ! This is the kind of trick I needed. In my case I removed the take(1) so on the first call I get only the last value and then it subscribe as usual.